# C++ project using SiLab's Precision32 IDE for SiM3L 32 bit microcontrollers

Tags: c++, cortex-m

We are new on Precision32 IDE and Silabs 32 bit MCUs; we tryed to develop some C code without any problems, but we are unable to build any C++ code. Silabs  do not provide any example in C++, neither we get any answer from Silabs support. Do you know if it is possible with this IDE to develop in C++ for SIM3L uC? If yes, do you have any "hello" world working project example with the proper toolchain? Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe the exact symptoms? Surely, if the system supports C++, a simple `cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;` should do the trick of printing something. If that doesn't compile, then you probably need a different compiler. On the other hand, if the processor only has 8KB of RAM, it may be tough to fit a useful C++ program into it?

Comment: @Mats the SIM3L we are using has 256kB flash memory and 32kB RAM [link](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/SiM3L1xx.pdf). We are using the Eclipse based Precision32 IDE from Silabs [link](http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/32-bit-mcu-software.aspx#library) probably developed by code_red.Simply passing from a main.c to a main.cpp project we have these errors on compiling time:

Comment: @MatsPetersson 
-make *** [sim3l1xx_UART.axf] Erro1 - Resource: sim3l1xx_UART - Type: C/C++ Problem
-more undefined reference to '_assertion_failed' follow - Resource: SI32_PBSTD_A_Type.c- Type: C/C++ Problem
- undefined reference to '_assertion_failed' - Resource: SI32_CLKCTRL_A_Type.c - Path: /sim3l1xx_UART/src/sim3l1xx - Location line 112 - Type: C/C++ Problem
... and other 20 similar errors.

Comment: So, you are missing the "assertion_failed" function... I don't know where you find it, but it should be part of the standard library. You could try looking at the `assert.h` to see if there is a way to turn off asserts - which should work around the problem.

Comment: probably but since we got plenty of that errors we'd like to understand what's wrong passing from C compiling for which there are no problems to C++ compiling when we get that unlucky result. anyway we'll look to that header file. thanks.

Comment: Probably just that none of the C code uses assert...